# What's the state of support for SHA-2 in various platforms?

Tags: security, hash, sha2

[I read that SHA-1 is being retired from the FIPS 180-2 standard.](http://gcn.com/articles/2010/03/03/rsa-sha-competition.aspxhttp://gcn.com/articles/2010/03/03/rsa-sha-competition.aspx)

Apparently there are weaknesses in SHA-1 that led to this decision.  Can anyone elaborate on the basis for that decision?  Are there implications for the use of SHA-1 in commercial applications?

My real questions are:

- *What is the state of SHA-2 support in various class libraries and platforms?*
- *Should I attempt to move to SHA-2*?

Interested in mainstream platforms:  .NET, Java, C/C++, Python, Javascript, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sha1, Sha0, md4 and md5 have all been found to be insecure over the past few years.  The problem is that if an attacker can generate 2 different messages that produce the same resulting hash, this is called a collision.  This causes a lot of problems for PKI's, password management, file integrity checks and more.  Currently sha1 only provides 2^52 bits of security which is within reach of attackers.  Where as SHA-256 (smallest member of the sha2 family) is provides 2^256 bits.

All platforms should have a SHA-256 implementation,  although not all of them are native.   In PHP you have to use the mhash extension. Its rather baffling that some platforms don't provide secure hash functions,  I honestly believe its because they don't care about secuirty.  In the case of PHP I know for a fact that [they don't care about secuirty](http://blog.php-security.org/archives/61-Retired-from-securityphp.net.html).

Currently there is nothing wrong with SHA-2 and it has a very large margin of safety.  You can use SHA-512 if you are *really* paranoid.   Sha-3 will be out in 2012, you should patch whatever you can with sha-2 like your **PASSWORDS**, and then move to SHA-3 when you can but SHA-512 will be good for a VERY long time.

Comment: @edgar as long as php lacks basic secuirty features,  like secure hash function,  then this is still very relevant. I can't change facts based on what you think.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Vista and later supports SHA-2 in the Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider for CryptoAPI, and the .NET Framework has supported SHA-2 since .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Most platforms now support the SHA-2 family. However, SHA-1 is still used in many applications, like SSL, and will be in use for a while.

A competition for "SHA-3" is well underway. It might be reasonable to jump from SHA-1 to the new SHA-3 standard when it arrives.

Comment: sha3 is a few years away,  i'd make sure your protected by moving to sha2 asap.  Its only 1 function call change,  it shouldn't be a big deal for most apps (an entire PKI is a different story and that will take time to patch)

Comment: Often, switching is not an option. For example, maybe a SHA-256 TLS cipher suite isn't supported by a partner. And it's not a problem, because even if there is a vulnerability, it can't be exploited fast enough to forge MACs in a network protocol.

Comment: Hash collisions don't affect message authentication codes,  they also don't affect Media Access Control addresses.  Sha-3 will be out in 2012,  you should patch whatever you can with sha-2 like your **PASSWORDS**.