# SHA2 And TLS1 / SSL3

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, sha2

I have a web service that is currently being used by a variety of old .Net and Java clients using TLS1.0/SSl3 protocols using a SHA1 certificate.

If I were to change the certificate to be SHA2 would these clients still work ?

I am changing no other configurations on the server (i.e. not disabling TLS1 /SS3).

I will overtime when I can get the clients to upgrade to use TLS1.2.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/ for details on SSL/TLS versions on Windows. Note that the main table only shows what versions are supported, not which versions are enabled!

Comment: Compatibility list of SHA-2 certificates can be found here: https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1499561-sha-256-compatibility

Answer (score 0):

.NET supports SHA2 since 1.1 (see [What's the state of support for SHA-2 in various platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405529/whats-the-state-of-support-for-sha-2-in-various-platforms/2405611#2405611))

Java supports SHA2 since 1.4.2. (see https://www.entrust.com/should-you-use-sha-2/)

If you have access to these clients, and if they can connect to a different URL that uses a SHA2 certificate, you should be good. Give the users/ maintainers of these clients a date when you will be migrating your service to use a SHA2 certificate so that they can test it themselves.

Comment: I don't have access to the clients so I cannot control when they will upgrade.  However my SHA1 certificate runs out soon so I just wanted a heads up as to if the clients will continue to work against a new SHA2 certificate.  i.e. the SHA2 certificate is backwards compatible with SSL3 and TLS1.0.

Comment: @ady: The signature algorithm of the certificate is unrelated to the SSL/TLS protocol version. This means there might be clients which can do TLS 1.0 but cannot do SHA-2 signed certificates.

Comment: If a platform supports SHA2 this does not necessarily means it supports it in SSL/TLS. E.g. AFAIK on Windows the SSL implementation is part of the OS and not of .Net.